# To customize Bootstrap Typeahead dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using Bootstrap dropdown and I have set the limit of values to be shown as 12 which is by default 5.
So the requirement is that if in case the items for that typeAhead is more than 12 we need to show 12 (as in set limit as 12) and also create a new entry in the dropdown with a '...' meaning that there are more values and the user needs to filter the search like in the below diagram.

[The sample I have created where only on first set of data '...' is shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAz2Z.png)

So basically, I type a character in the input box and the autosuggestion appears according to the limit set, but if the values present is more than the limit with the suggested values also need to add a new entry to dropdown i.e '...' like in the image below.

here is the link to the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAz2Z.png)
So can anyone help me here with what I have to do here?

Thanks,
Varun

Comment: update your question with working link to image and live example your markup's issue

Comment: Hey Igor, I have updated the question with the working link.

Comment: but where is your code?)

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [codepen](http://codepen.io/) or [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)